# Ошибка при проверке пустой ли Объект. Почему выходит ошибка при проверке?

Tags: javascript, объекты

```js
let salaries = {
  John: 100,
  Ann: 160,
  Pete: 130,
};


function isEmptyObject(obj) {
  for (let el in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(el))
      console.log("is not empty");
    else
      console.log("is not empty");

  };


  isEmptyObject(salaries);
```

Comment: Можно попробовать закрыть скобку в конце для function, вы открыли две скобки (function и for) закрыли одну :)

Comment: Посмотрите очень короткую запись на проверку объекта на [стаковерфлоу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32108184/14135825) `obj && Object.keys(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object`